# Update in apps, not from market

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play

I have installed  `mySample.apk` on device, 
  and i `download updates` for app `from MY server`
 then 
  install(`replace`) appk, but android `SAY:`

"**this package already installed!**"

I know that in applications the same keys and versions and certificate , but change them does not work, how do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the `android:versionCode="1"` on your AndroidManifest to a new version? if not Package manager will not know if it's newer that the previously installed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i changed android:versionCode="1"  - not working   i dont now how change signing in my apps

Comment: No, Try to change the versionCode to a value higher that the previous installation was.